# How to add properties to Woocommerce account?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add some properties to my accounts in woocommerce (ie: eyes color)
In the codex, I've found solutions to add fields into checkout but I do not need these informations in checkout, I want them editable into the account page.
Is there a programmatically solution (or a plugin) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom user field using `update_user_meta` function . Please read 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

or read this 
https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's seems to be a good starting point. With, do I need to find forms to add the new property ? I need for example to add into the user form a checkbox with colors as options.

Comment: check this plugin and let me know https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife/